# Scala and parameters of unapply function

Tags: scala

I have a simple `unapply` that checks of an integer is less than 10

```
object MatchLess {
    def unapply(i: Int): Option[Int] = if ( i < 10 ) Some(i) else None
}

// so this prints
// 7 8 9 . . .
for ( i <- 7 to 12 ) i match {
    case MatchLess(x) => print(x + " ") // line 8
    case _ => print(". ")
}
```

I have one doubt about `unapply` syntax: why in `case` in line 8, value `x` is actually visible at both sides of `=>`? Can I assume that the compiler implicitly adds an assignment like this?

```
// ...
case /* val x = i */ MatchLess(x) => print(x + " ") // line 8
```

Comment: `MatchLess(x)` is just binding `x` in the pattern; why do you think something is being defined implicitly?

Comment: for `case MatchLess(x)` unapply is called: `MatchLess.unapply(x)` that returns `Option[Int]` that I later use as `x`. I see no place where `x` is defined, that's why I ask.

Answer (score 7):

When you write `case MatchLess(x) => ...` the meaning is the following:

1. execute the unapply method
2. if it succeed, bind the variables (here `x`) to the values returned by `unapply` here the `i` of `Some(i)` (ohterwise, the pattern doesn't match, goes to the following.

So **in your particular case** the `x` is bound to the same value than `i`. But if instead of `Some(i)`the function `MatchLess.unapply`returns something else (for example `Some(42)`) x would have been bound to `42`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [the language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/198), section 8 on pattern matching:

```
Syntax:
Pattern ::= Pattern1 { ‘|’ Pattern1 }
Pattern1 ::= varid ‘:’ TypePat
| ‘_’ ‘:’ TypePat
| Pattern2
Pattern2 ::= varid [‘@’ Pattern3]
| Pattern3
Pattern3 ::= SimplePattern
| SimplePattern {id [nl] SimplePattern}
SimplePattern ::= ‘_’
| varid                                                 // <- 2)
| Literal
| StableId
| StableId ‘(’ [Patterns] ‘)’                           // <- 1)
| StableId ‘(’ [Patterns ‘,’] [varid ‘@’] ‘_’ ‘*’ ‘)’
| ‘(’ [Patterns] ‘)’
| XmlPattern
Patterns ::= Pattern {‘,’ Patterns}
```

`MatchLess(x)` is identified as a `SimplePattern` (1), and the expression between parentheses, according to the above, is identified via Patterns -> Pattern -> Pattern1 -> Pattern2 -> Pattern3 -> SimplePattern -> varid (2). This variable pattern is described as:

> A variable pattern *x* is a simple identifier which starts with a lower
>   case letter. It matches any value, and binds the variable name to that
>   value. The type of x is the expected type of the pattern as given from
>   outside.

In your example, `unapply` is called on `i`, and the *result* is bound to `x`.